# excel mround() bug workaround

Tags: microsoft-excel

This is MSFT's explanation of the MROUND bug:

> When a ﻿decimal value is provided to the Multiple argument, the rounding direction is undefined for midpoint numbers. For example MROUND(6.05,0.1) returns 6.0 while MROUND(7.05,0.1) returns 7.1.

MSFT blames the IEEE for this bug.

What is a workaround for an equivalent of MROUND(6.05,0.1) returning 6.1? Should I use floor() or ceiling() in combination with adding or subtracting a decimal number?

Comment: Don't use `MROUND`. Use the `ROUND` function instead.

Comment: Ceiling &  Mround both do the same, in case of 6.05 only Mround produces 6 but Ceiling gives 6.01. So better use the Ceiling .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest ditching the `MROUND(Number, 0.1)` command altogether and use multiplication and the ceiling function. Such as `0.1*CEILING.MATH(10*(Number - 0.0499))`. If a function is that buggy, I wouldn't want it in my code.

Comment: I'd guess that `CEILING` would not, well, round? So indeed, like the OP suggested, one probably needs to subtract 0.5, then use above `CEILING` trick, and add the 0.5 again?

Comment: Ceiling does round. It take a value, and then rounds it to the nearest whole number greater than itself. So if you multiply by 10 and then take the ceiling, you will be round to the nearest decimal in the tenths place. I think this should work.

Comment: If it always rounds up, then I assume it's not the same as `MROUND`.

Comment: I see. But you could solve that by subtracting... no need to add or use mround.

Comment: @ron-rosenfeld raises an important point about using `ROUND()` because the consensus from engineers is that values should be calculated in whole numbers (eg. whole cents, not dollar decimals [and i have to rewrite all my accounting spreadsheets to do this])